# Limit user to submit the form

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a HTML form where data is filled and submitted.Now i want to limit the users to hit submit i.e i want only set of users whom i want to hit submit,if any other person hits the submit a message should display as "You are not authorized to submit".

Example form is :

```
<html>
<?php echo ( !empty($_SESSION ['user']) ) ? $_SESSION ['user'] : 'USER'; ?>
<body>
<form action="action_page.php">
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname" value="firstname">
  <br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname" value="lastname">
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form> 
</body>
</html>
```

Here i would get the usernames from :

```
<?php echo ( !empty($_SESSION ['user']) ) ? $_SESSION ['user'] : 'USER'; ?>
```

This "user" am collecting from the login page.Who ever logs in with their credentials their user name will be passed through the pages for the sake of session.

Here "user" i want only particular users to be able to submit.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you are talking about permissions?

Comment: And where are you using jQuery?

Comment: Don't you find it easier not even show a submit button when the user is not allowed to use it? (Just curiosity)

Comment: It would be better to not show the form to a user that cannot make changes, or at least not put the submit button on the form at all for users that cannot press it. That can all be achieved from the PHP code that generates the form

Comment: This is actually a sample form..,in actual form i have other information which has to be displayed to all the users..

@Ed de Almeida yes the close button can be hidden for un-authorised users.Can you let me know how that can be done

Comment: You certainly have a defined group for the authorized ones. Just add and <?php  if (user_in_authorized_group()) ?> around the submit button, with this method (or something similar) returning true if the user is allowed to submit, false otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

**EDIT :**

*Since the OP wants to show button to only MANAGERS, we'll write a query to get those users.*

```
$sel='Select `usergroup` from table_name where user_id='.$_SESSION['user'];
$res=mysqli_query($con,$sel);
$row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
?>

<form action="action_page.php">
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname" value="firstname">
  <br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname" value="lastname">
  <br><br>

  <?php 
  // did changes here

  if($row['usergroup']=='manager') // those users who are manager
  { 
    ?>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
    <?php 
  } ?>
</form> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: All the users will be able to login,but in that all users only few should be able to submit..but here who ever logs in will be able to submit

Comment: So, what is your condition @user5358888, you want to show button to which user's ? Please mention the condition so that I can help you in that as well

Comment: I will echoing some info from db here,along with that there will be field for input.everyone should be able to view the data that is being echoed but only few users should be able to submit with some information typed in it..For example employees should be able to view the info but only managers should be able to type the information and submit it

Comment: @user5358888, so there must be any condition/group in your db like MANAGER, so we can manage using that

Answer (score 1):

you need a database table where user specific permission store . After getting login user from session then write a select query if the user has this permission then show the form otherwise hide the form and display message

Comment: i want the form to be displayed but need permissions only to the submit button,as i have other information that has to be visible to all the users

Answer (score 1):

... and remove the form-node for users that are not allowed to submit, since you can trigger the submit by pressing enter for example.

Basically sepearte the whole thing into two templates:

- one with the form for the users u want to be able to submit,
- and one without any form-elements (use regular nodes instead: divs, spans, ...) for the ones u only want to show data.
  because it doesn't make sense to have/change an input-field if it does nothing.

Comment: I just posted this form as an example...but am echoing some data from the db.every user will be able to login but in that i want only few users to click submit others should just be able to view the info from the db..

Comment: I got that, but in the first step you disable the submit-button, then you come across issues, that the form was sent by pressing enter or so, then you'll probably mess around with the onsubmit-event-handler Then someone files an error, that he/she can't submit the form or anthing like that (aka. your page is broken, fix that immediately!), then ... whatever. Long way short: **seperate the views, show each group their respective view.** And don't show a form or inputs, if the user can't use them. either by submitting the form, or some JS updating the view.

Comment: Can you please let me know how to separate the views for the users ?

Comment: By separating the template into two different files/functions/classes that create the markup for one respective group and you have only to choose wich one to call at this place. mixing the templates will get more complicated as soon as you have to manage a third group or if the views start to drift apart (you say that won't happen; I've said that often enough too, and was wrong). If you have concerns about redundancy, split off these shared parts into foreign files/functions/modules; I'm don't want to say that you should repeat yourself.